# Adding components to JPanel, No Change on screen

Tags: java, animation, jpanel

I am doing a small animation/xml file creation editor for a private game i am making.
I have a JPanel where I add some custom components, but I never see any change.

Custom Component:

```
public class BasicProprety extends JPanel {
String key;
String value;

    public BasicProprety(String k, String v) {
        key = k;
        value = v;
        JTextField keyField = new JTextField(k);
        JTextField valueField = new JTextField(v);
        valueField.setVisible(true);
        keyField.setVisible(true);
        this.add(keyField);
        this.add(valueField);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I use a static method to refresh properties of the current frame :

```
 public static void refreshFrameProperties() {
    Frame currentFrame = DataBank.getCurrentInstance().getCurrentFrameObj();
    BasicProprety millisecs = new BasicProprety("millisecondsTillNextFrame", String.valueOf(currentFrame.getMillisecondsToNextFrame()));
    BasicProprety offsetX = new BasicProprety("offsetX", String.valueOf(currentFrame.getOffset().x));
    BasicProprety offsetY = new BasicProprety("offsetY", String.valueOf(currentFrame.getOffset().y));
    BasicProprety sizeX = new BasicProprety("sizeX", String.valueOf(currentFrame.getSize().x));
    BasicProprety sizeY = new BasicProprety("sizeY", String.valueOf(currentFrame.getSize().y));
    sizeX.revalidate();
    sizeY.revalidate();
    offsetY.revalidate();
    offsetX.revalidate();
    millisecs.revalidate();
    sizeX.repaint();
    sizeY.repaint();
    offsetY.repaint();
    offsetX.repaint();
    millisecs.repaint();
    ArrayList<BasicProprety> basicList = new ArrayList<BasicProprety>();
    for (int i = 0; i < mainInterface.getProperties().getComponentCount(); i++) {
        if (mainInterface.getProperties().getComponent(i) instanceof BasicProprety)
            basicList.add((BasicProprety)mainInterface.getProperties().getComponent(i));
    }
    for (BasicProprety bp : basicList) {
        mainInterface.getProperties().remove(bp);
    }
    mainInterface.getProperties().revalidate();
    mainInterface.getProperties().repaint();
    System.out.println("REMOVED: "+mainInterface.getProperties().getComponentCount());
    mainInterface.getProperties().getLayout().addLayoutComponent("TEST", sizeY);
    mainInterface.getProperties().add(millisecs);
    mainInterface.getProperties().add(offsetX);
    mainInterface.getProperties().add(offsetY);
    mainInterface.getProperties().add(sizeX);
    mainInterface.getProperties().add(sizeY);
    /*Random r = new Random();
    mainInterface.getProperties().setBackground(new Color(r.nextInt()));*/
    mainInterface.getProperties().revalidate();
    mainInterface.getProperties().repaint();
    mainInterface.getProperties().setVisible(true);
    System.out.println("NO: "+mainInterface.getProperties().getComponentCount());

}
```

My component is created with the netbeans interface editor and this is the creation code:

```
    properties = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout propertiesLayout = new org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout(properties);
    properties.setLayout(propertiesLayout);
    propertiesLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        propertiesLayout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
        .add(0, 243, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    propertiesLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        propertiesLayout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
        .add(0, 386, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
```

Comment: Irrelevant, but `BasicProprety` is spelled incorrectly. May be helpful in the future to correct it.

Comment: Yeppe, thanks i had problems finding the autocompletion for that class, thank's to you I know why!

Comment: You might also want to keep `mainInterface.getProperties()` in a local variable so it makes your code easier to follow, e.g. `... properties.revalidate(); properties.repaint(); ...` vs what you have now.

Answer (score 1):

They are propably added, but not to your `Component` but rather the **contentPane**. `JPanel.getContentPane()` which is the one and only component of your `JPanel`.

Not sure though.

Comment: I just tried and the ContentPane has only 3 ?!? instead of 5 sub components, but the number never changes though i remove all before adding new ones.

Answer (score 0):

The error in the component count is that you're checking `mainInterface.getComponentCount()`, rather than `mainInterface.getProperties().getComponentCount()`. Presumably `mainInterface` only contains your `JPanel`?

You can avoid similar errors to these by using a local variable, e.g.

```
final JPanel properties = mainInterface.getProperties();
...
System.out.println("number of properties' components: "
                       + properties.getComponentCount());
```

---

By the way, you can simplify the following loop...

```
ArrayList<BasicProprety> basicList = new ArrayList<BasicProprety>();
for (int i = 0; i < mainInterface.getProperties().getComponentCount(); i++) {
    if (mainInterface.getProperties().getComponent(i) instanceof BasicProprety)
        basicList.add((BasicProprety)mainInterface.getProperties().getComponent(i));
}
for (BasicProprety bp : basicList) {
    mainInterface.getProperties().remove(bp);
}
```

... into this:

```
for (Component component : properties.getComponents()) {
  if (component instanceof BasicProperty) {
    properties.remove(component);
  }
}
```

Make sure all of your UI modifications are done in the context of the event dispatch thread.

(PS does anyone else think `Container` should expose an `Iterator<Component>` somehow?)

Comment: I just tried that, my components were added correctly all the way, but no component ever appears on screen

Comment: You're not iterating the internal list `Container` uses for its children components; `properties.getComponents()` returns a copy of the components in a `Component[]`... don't worry!